# QGIS 3 - Snap line feature endpoints within certain tolerance to other line features

Tags: qgis-3, line, network, snapping, endpoints

I have a line layer in QGIS 3.22.12 with which I want to create a network. However I've found quite a few lines where the endpoint does not quite intersect with another line. Is it possible to clean up the layer by snapping endpoints within a certain tolerance to other lines in one process?

Comment: Do you want to do this manually or automatically?

Comment: Automatically as there are quite a lot of lines. Manually I would use the intersection option in the digitising toolbar

Comment: Maybe have a look at GRASS tools like `v.net.connectivity`

Answer (score 3):

1. Use "Extract vertices" from processing toolbox to turn "the other lines" into points. You can also densify the lines first or run "Points along geometry".
2. Use "Snap Vertices to nearest Points by Condition" from [ProcessX PlugIn](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/ProcessX/) to snap your line endpoints to the vertices of the other lines. You can find this tool in your processing toolbox as well.

Comment: Thanks will try that. What do you mean by 'densify the lines'?

Comment: That means adding more vertices to the lines.